# ASP.NET Application Breaks When Connection String Uses Alias Instead of Server Name

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dns, alias, impersonation

I have an ASP.NET web application (Windows Web Server 2008 R2, ASP.NET 4.0).  It access a database using a connection string like the following:

```
Data Source=hindenburg;Initial Catalog=ABC;Integrated Security=True
```

"hindenburg" is the name of the SQL server.  Impersonation is turned on.  Because we are moving our databases, I wish to switch from "hindenburg to a HOST (A) alias, "SQLptABC".  Ergo, the new connection string is:

```
Data Source=SQLptABC;Initial Catalog=ABC;Integrated Security=True
```

SQLptABC points to hindenburg's IP address.  However, now when I use the app, I get the error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'." upon trying to read the database.  This is a repeatable error; just changing "hindenburg" to "SQLptABC" breaks things.

It appears that the impersonation being used by IIS and my app to access the database is being broken when I use the alias.  Is it adding an extra "hop", turning my two-hop situation into a three-hop situation?  Or is the problem that "hindenburg" is trusted somewhere, while "SQLptABC" is not?

(My apologies if my DNS terminology isn't quite right.  That's not my usual ambit.)

Comment: The name of the server is "hindenburg"?   Oh, the humanity.

Comment: Well, start asking your admin about his job. Are you using Kerberos? If yes - there must be a SPN for Hindenburg registered. Which he has to do (and you have to ask). NTLM? Not sure that works.